# Import node module in Storybook Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, storybook

I want all stories to have the styling of elementPlus, but it's not importing correctly. I have tried to do it with a wrapper, but it doesn't actually use elementPlus. How can I load elementPlus inside all stories?

Preview.js:

```
import elementPlus from 'element-plus';
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/vue3';

addDecorator(() => ({
  template: '<div style="color: red;"><elementPlus><story/></elementPlus></div>',
}));
```

Main.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../plugins/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../plugins/**/*.stories.mdx',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: false
          }
        },
        { loader: 'sass-loader' }
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// storybook/preview.js

import { app } from '@storybook/vue3';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css';

app.use(ElementPlus);

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

After you can see this error message **Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)**

To resolve problem add webpackFinal config in main.js

```
// storybook/main.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
    "../src/**/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/vue3",
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      type: 'javascript/auto'
    });

    return config;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to set element-plus to be global.

@storybook/vue3: "^6.3.8"
@vue/cli-service: "~4.5.0"
element-plus: "^1.1.0-beta.12"

Preview.js:

```js
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import '../node_modules/element-plus/theme-chalk/index.css';
import { storybookApp } from '../node_modules/@storybook/vue3/dist/esm/client/preview/render';
storybookApp.use(ElementPlus);
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it can be used.

If you have good answer, shared with me please. Thank you!

Comment: @storybook/vue3(6.4.9) and element-plus(1.3.0-beta.1) not work